# How to maximize dash using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys, unity-dash

Are there any keyboard shortcut to maximize dash?

Comment: Have you solved this question?

Answer (score 1):

A shortcut for this doesn't currently exist, but a bug exists that documents the lack of this feature.

If you [subscribe to Bug #842683](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/842683/+subscribe), you can be notified when the bug has been fixed and the functionality has been added.